# Does http 307 (temporary redirect) accepts cookie value revalidated at the server end?

Tags: redirect, cookies, request, http-post, http-status-code-307

I am invoking a POST request (say **request A**) from my browser. And I’m trying to do the following at my backend while redirecting the request,

```
1) Clear a cookie value

2) Set 307 header value and

3) Adding Location header with redirect url (say request B) value.
```

(2) and (3) works fine.

(1) is not working as expected. When the **request B** is invoked the cookie value is not cleared - it reuses the value in request A. Can someone provide me some insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have appropriate Set-Cookie headers in the response of A.
Some of web application frameworks cannot add those headers in usual way when redirecting.

I've tested that Chrome and Edge (40.15063) handle Set-Cookie expectedly (and thus clear cookies) in 307 redirects by using this simple CGI:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Status: 307 Temporary Redirect
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
printf 'Set-Cookie: Your-Cookie=; path=/; domain=Your-Domain; expires=%s' "$(date --rfc-2822 --utc --date='1 day ago')"
echo "Location: Your-B-url"
echo
```